# where does spring security takes values to replace wild card?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-security

I have read following article:

[jdbc-user-service-based-spring-security-example](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/16/jdbc-user-service-based-spring-security-example/)

spring configuration:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"

       users-by-username-query="
         SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD, CASE ENABLED WHEN 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END 'ENABLED'
         FROM TBL_USERS
         WHERE USERNAME=?;"

       authorities-by-username-query="
        SELECT u.USERNAME, r.ROLENAME
        FROM TBL_USERS u, TBL_USER_ROLE r
        WHERE u.ID = r.USERID
        AND u.USERNAME=?;"

        />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Lets research following snippet:

```
users-by-username-query="
             SELECT USERNAME, PASSWORD, CASE ENABLED WHEN 1 THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END 'ENABLED'
             FROM TBL_USERS
             WHERE USERNAME=?;"
```

As I understand following query is query to all users can be login.
As I understand it is something like prepared statement. But when we use prepared statement we write somethng like this:

```
preparedStatement.setString(1, "John");
```

I don't understand where spring takes `USERNAME` value to replace `?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The username is the one submitted when you authenticate, and subsequently passed to the `UserDetailsService`. You can see where the actual substitution takes place if you look at [the code for the JDBC version](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/3.2.5.RELEASE/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.java#L192).

It uses Spring's `JdbcTemplate` and the [`query` method](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-) it calls does the substitution of the parameters in the prepared statement.